# ¿Cómo establecer el valor de una variable durante la instalación utilizando Visual Studio 2022 Installer Projects?

Tags: vb.net, windows-installer

Tengo una solución de Visual Studio con dos proyectos:

- DBManagerService: este proyecto contiene una clase llamada ProjectInstaller y el archivo ProjectInstaller.Designer.vb. El código correspondiente es el siguiente:

```
<System.ComponentModel.RunInstaller(True)> Partial Class ProjectInstaller
    Inherits System.Configuration.Install.Installer

    ' ... Other code ...

    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.ServiceProcessInstaller1 = New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller()
        Me.ServiceIntaller1 = New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller()

        ' ... Other code ...

        Me.ServiceIntaller1.ServiceName = serviceName

        ' ... Other code ...

    End Sub

    ' ... Other code ...

    Friend WithEvents ServiceProcessInstaller1 As System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller
    Friend WithEvents ServiceIntaller1 As System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller

End Class
```

And this is the ProjectInstaller.vb:

```
Public Class ProjectInstaller

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

        'This call is required by the Component Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        'Add initialization code after the call to InitializeComponent
        '' Me.ServiceIntaller1.ServiceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ServiceName")

    End Sub

    Private Sub ServiceIntaller1_AfterInstall(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Configuration.Install.InstallEventArgs) Handles ServiceIntaller1.AfterInstall

    End Sub

    Private Sub ServiceProcessInstaller1_AfterInstall(sender As Object, e As InstallEventArgs) Handles ServiceProcessInstaller1.AfterInstall

    End Sub
End Class
```

- PruebaInstalador: Este proyecto es un proyecto de instalación de tipo "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022" extensión. He agregado un cuadro de diálogo con un cuadro de texto y el valor de Edit1Property está establecido en "EDITA1".

Quiero que el valor de la variable Me.ServiceIntaller1.ServiceName se establezca durante la instalación con el valor ingresado por el usuario en Edit1. Para que así el usuario pueda elegir cual va a ser el nombre del servicio una vez instalado.

He intentado añadir "Context.Parameters("EDITA1")". Pero no soluciona el error. Además de intentar añadir controlador de eventos mediante código pero no lo consigo. En todas partes veo que se pueden añadir controlador desde la interfaz pero no me aparece el icono.

Comment: mmmm no... no creo que quieras hacer eso en el instalador.. si queres que el usuario modifique una configuracion, crea un archivo de configuracion...

Comment: me ha faltado añadir info al hilo perdón, no quiero que el usuario modifique una configuración, sino el nombre del servicio que aparece en "Servicios", que el usuario lo lo pueda introducir durante la instalación, pero no consigo añadir el controlador.